# ASP.net Web User Control

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webusercontrol

I created a web user control that contain a '`dropdownlist`' but unable to populate it, please any who can help me how to use `Dropdownlist` as web user control and load it from EF 4 model class

Comment: Are you doing it from code-behind or on the markup ?

Comment: Can you post some code or markup?

Comment: calling this method on page load but its not working public void Bindtvr()
        {
            
            TVRInfoManger tmg = new TVRInfoManger();
          
            ddltvr.DataSource = tmg.GetTVRId();
            ddltvr.DataTextField = "TVRID";
            ddltvr.DataValueField = "TVRID";
            ddltvr.DataBind();
        }

Comment: I m doing it from code behind

Comment: Is tmg.GetTVRId(); returning an empty list or is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code for binding to an ASP DropDownList:

```
        using (Entities1 ctx = new Entities1())
        {
            var lst = from u in ctx.SystemUsers
                      select u;

            ddl1.DataSource = lst;
            ddl1.DataTextField = "TVRID";
            ddl1.DataValueField = "TVRID";
            ddl1.DataBind();
        }
```

Where ctx.SystemUsers should be your tmg.GetTVRId();, can you tell us what TVRInfoManger is exactly doing?

Comment: no actually I was something and figured it out